# How to generate dynamic progress bar on windows form for parallel upload progress

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, windows, asyncfileupload

I have to create a Windows application where i will upload multiple file to azure file share storage and i need to show the multiple file upload progress using progress bar control in windows for application.

I want to show the dynamic progress bar on windows form with each upload iteration of file upload.

Can any one suggest with sample loop iteration for upload with multiple file using progress bar on windows form.

Comment: Is this blob storage?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. **Nor** is it a public code repository. Show us what you have done on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to *Blob Storage*.

[UploadFromFileAsync(String, AccessCondition, BlobRequestOptions, OperationContext, IProgress, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromfileasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_UploadFromFileAsync_System_String_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_System_IProgress_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Core_Util_StorageProgress__System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

> A IProgress object to handle StorageProgress messages.

[StorageProgress Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.core.util.storageprogress?view=azure-dotnet)

> Holds information about the progress data transfers for both request
>   and response streams in a single operation.

A nice little example on their site, allbeit a stream example

```
CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
IProgress<StorageProgress> progressHandler = new Progress<StorageProgress>(
    progress => Console.WriteLine("Progress: {0} bytes transferred", progress.BytesTransferred)
    );

await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(
    srcStream,
    default(AccessCondition),
    default(BlobRequestOptions),
    default(OperationContext),
    progressHandler,
    cancellationToken
    );
```

So where to from here. Because this is *IO bound* work its best **not** use `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` its a waste of resources.

However, [ActionBlock Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) in the [TPL dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) can be suited, or just `async`/`await` pattern with [Task.WaitAll Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Dataflow example**

```
var block = new ActionBlock<MySomething>(
    mySomething => MyMethodAsync(mySomething),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 });

foreach (var something in ListOfSomethings)
{
    block.Post(something );
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

So without writing the rest of the code for you

1. Simply add up the size in bytes of your files before you start youy transfers.
2. Create your progress handlers, and associate them with your tasks

   - Possibly keep the transferred amount with your tasks
3. On progress (in thread safe manner) or just on a timmer (in a thread safe manner) sum your progress against the expected amount

Obviously there are details left out of here, however you are now a programmer and its your mission (if you choose to accept it) to figure it out.. free lunch given, and i look forward to your next questions about everything in between :)

Comment: Sorry let me clear more on it. I want to display the progress bar instead of showing the progress in Console message. I am using windows application and i want to bind the progress information with progress bar

Comment: So instead of showing this message Console.WriteLine("Progress: {0} bytes transferred", progress.BytesTransferred) i want to display byte transferred by progress bar control of Windows form